# is this 12V power supply functioning properly and will it power my device?

Tags: voltage, serial, soldering, adapter, pinout

I have purchased a Rhino 12V DC CCTV Camera Power Adapter. The specs are Input 100-240 VAC, Output 12V DC. I cut off the 2.1mm plug and currently have the Red (Power?) and Black (Negative?) wires stripped ready to solder. My first concern is that when using a continuity tester, I put the alligator clip of the tester on the black wire and the needle on the red wire and I have continuity. When I flip flop the two there is no continuity. Also I have not found any continuity when I test the prongs to the wires in any arrangement. I am not familiar with this hardware so if anyone can shed light on this I would appreciate it.

Also I have a device that can be powered through a DB9 serial port. When looking at the Pinout however I would like some confirmation on which wires to solder to. The pins that are relevant are labeled as (5) Ground,  (6) 120VAC Charger Input, and (9) Voltage Input External voltage input 6VDC-16 VDC.  My thought is to solder the Red wire from the 12VDC adapter to pin 9 on the serial cable and the Black wire to the 5 Ground wire. Then I could simply plug my power adapter (now with the DB9  end) into an outlet and into my device. This is assuming that my power adapter is functioning properly.

Opinions and ideas appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no generic answer to this because there is no generic power supply design so, either find some data on the device and present it here or try and figure it yourself. Asking for opinions means you haven't read or understood the rules for asking questions on this site.

Comment: Do you have a DMM?  I'd measure the voltage before assuming red = positive.  (though it probably is.)

Comment: Andy you've apparently misinterpreted my opinions and ideas bit. I am only looking for useful information, not a lesson in how to use the site. The questions are 1) from the information does it sound like my power supply is malfunctioning or have you heard of a power supply having continuity as such. 2) Am I correct in my thinking with the wires I would solder together. I'm not looking for a chat or discussion, just answers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your power adptor is OK.  There should be no connection between the AC input pins and the DC output.  Whether the two DC output terminals should show continuity or not will depend on the circuit inside the power adaptor.  I wouldn't be surprised to measure continuity with one polarity of the meter, and not continuity with the other. (Measuring the continuity/resistance of the output of a power supply is fairly meaningless - measuring voltage is much more useful.)

The continuity test on a multimeter indicates a low resistance connection (perhaps under 100 Ohms) between the probes - not necessarily a short circuit (zero Ohms)

Your suggested connections to the DE-9 connector are correct, assuming that the red wire from the supply is positive.